# Reprojecting Xarray Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray, cartopy, pyproj, metpy

I'm trying to reproject a Lambert Conformal dataset to Plate Carree. I know that this can easily be done visually using cartopy. However, I'm trying to create a new dataset rather than just show a reprojected image. Below is methodology I have mapped out but I'm unable to subset the dataset properly (Python 3.5, MacOSx).

```
from siphon.catalog import TDSCatalog
import xarray as xr
from xarray.backends import NetCDF4DataStore
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy.ma as ma
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import metpy

# Declare bounding box
min_lon = -78
min_lat = 36
max_lat = 40
max_lon = -72
boundinglat = [min_lat, max_lat]
boundinglon = [min_lon, max_lon]

# Load the dataset
cat = TDSCatalog('https://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/grib/NCEP/HRRR/CONUS_2p5km/latest.xml')
dataset_name = sorted(cat.datasets.keys())[-1]
dataset = cat.datasets[dataset_name]
ds = dataset.remote_access(service='OPENDAP')
ds = NetCDF4DataStore(ds)
ds = xr.open_dataset(ds)

# parse the temperature at 850 and @ 0z reftime
tempiso = ds.metpy.parse_cf('Temperature_isobaric')
t850 = tempiso[0][2]

# transform bounding lat/lons to src_proj
src_proj = tempiso.metpy.cartopy_crs #aka lambert conformal conical
extents = src_proj.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), np.array(boundinglon), np.array(boundinglat))

# subset the data using the indexes of the closest values to the src_proj extents
t850_subset = t850[(np.abs(tempiso.y.values - extents[1][0])).argmin():(np.abs(tempiso.y.values - extents[1][1])).argmin()][(np.abs(tempiso.x.values - extents[0][1])).argmin():(np.abs(tempiso.x.values - extents[0][0])).argmin()]

# t850_subset should be a small, reshaped dataset, but it's shape is 0x2145
# now use nplinspace, npmeshgrid & scipy interpolate to reproject
```

My transform point > find nearest value subsetting isn't working. It's claiming the closest points are outside the realm of the dataset. As noted, I plan to use nplinspace, npmeshgrid and scipy interpolate to create a new, square lat/lon dataset from t850_subset.

**Is there an easier way to resize & reproject an xarray dataset?**

Comment: What is the shape (numrows, numcols) of the acquired dataset?

Comment: @swatchai the shape is 1377 x 2145

Comment: If you can convert `t850` to numpy's array, then, the array can be cropped or sliced to get the subset portion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your easiest path forward is to take advantage of xarray's ability to do pandas-like data selection; this is IMO the best part of xarray. Replace your last two lines with:

```
# By transposing the result of transform_points, we can unpack the
# x and y coordinates into individual arrays.
x_lim, y_lim, _ = src_proj.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    np.array(boundinglon), np.array(boundinglat)).T
t850_subset = t850.sel(x=slice(*x_lim), y=slice(*y_lim))
```

You can find more information in the documentation on xarray's [selection and indexing functionality](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html). You would probably also be interested in xarray's [built-in support for interpolation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html). And if interpolation methods beyond SciPy's are of interest, MetPy also has a suite of [other interpolation methods](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.interpolate.html#module-metpy.interpolate).

Answer (score 1):

We have various "regridding" methods in [Iris](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/index.html), if that isn't too much of a context switch for you.
Xarray explains its relationship to Iris [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/faq.html#what-other-netcdf-related-python-libraries-should-i-know-about), and provides [a to_iris() method](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_iris.html#xarray.DataArray.to_iris).